# Custom HID Gamepad works on Windows, has some inverted buttons in Linux

Tags: usb, stm32, hid, joystick, gamepad

I've designed a custom gamepad using an STM32. It has four analog axes, and 22 buttons. I have written firmware for it, including the USB Descriptor (that took a few tries).

It works exactly as expected on Windows, but on Linux (Raspbian specifically) the last 5 buttons are inverted ("on" by default, "off" when pressed)

It is critical to my product that it work on both platforms (Mac too, but I don't have one to test right now)

Any ideas why this would be, and what to do about it?

Here's the output of lsusb -v for this device:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0483:5750 STMicroelectronics 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0483 STMicroelectronics
  idProduct          0x5750 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 STMicroelectronics
  iProduct                2 STM32 Custom Human interface
  iSerial                 3 74E79C303734
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0029
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      53
          Report Descriptor: (length is 53)
            Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                            Generic Desktop Controls
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x05 ] 5
                            Gamepad
            Item(Main  ): Collection, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                            Application
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                            Pointer
            Item(Main  ): Collection, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
                            Physical
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x30 ] 48
                            Direction-X
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x31 ] 49
                            Direction-Y
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x32 ] 50
                            Direction-Z
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x33 ] 51
                            Rotate-X
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x0f ] 4095
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x10 ] 16
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x04 ] 4
            Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Main  ): End Collection, data=none
            Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x09 ] 9
                            Buttons
            Item(Local ): Usage Minimum, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                            Button 1 (Primary)
            Item(Local ): Usage Maximum, data= [ 0x16 ] 22
                            (null)
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x16 ] 22
            Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
            Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x03 ] 3
                            Constant Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Main  ): End Collection, data=none
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval              10
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

[image: What I am seeing in Linux, no buttons pressed]

[image: What I am seeing in Windows, no buttons pressed]

I also just noticed that the stick positions are different (again, correct on Windows, and wrong on Linux.)

I did read something about Linux having a kernel driver that does something to these values? jstest-gtk lets me control some aspects of the axes (scaling, dead zones, inversion) maybe that's a clue?

Comment: You might want to add information to your question, e.g. the report descriptors and sample reports showing on/off, otherwise you'd probably only get guesses. You could also try using something like [Hidviz](https://github.com/ondrejbudai/hidviz/)(which I haven't tried, so can't vouch for).

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks for the suggestion on updating the question, as well as Hidviz, I'll try that out.

Comment: I'm no joystick expert but, from my reading of the ArchWiki docs, the jstest program uses the old Joystick API interface rather than the new evdev API - so it may be a limitation of the old API. But first, I would verify that the USB packets flowing are actually correct by starting a Wireshark USB packet capture and pressing each button in turn. The payload should have 1 for pressed and 0 for not pressed. If it is otherwise then maybe the STM is sending incorrect payloads.

Comment: @aja Thank you, I'll read up on endev, and I'll try wireshark (I also have an oscilloscope that can capture the USB signals at the electrical level) but if the STM32 was sending the packets wrong, then why does everything come through as expected on Windows.......